# Difference in solarized gvim theme

Tags: python, vim

I am using a Solarized theme for (g)vim, and having an issue with small difference between the screenshot on the site and what I am actually having.

The screenshot for python on the theme's site is here: [image: here]
<sub>(source: [ethanschoonover.com](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/img/screen-python-dark.png))</sub>
, and mine is [image: this]

They have a small difference (that I can see) in import statement (color is different). It sort of drives me crazy. Is my case correct, and that's what supposed to happen, or my settings are wrong?

I've installed the theme using vim-addon-manager plugin system.

Thanks.

Comment: It's possible that he uses a different syntax file than you, with a different rule for `import`. Did you try to type the same code as in the screenshot?

Comment: @romainl yes, I have. No matter where I use import, it's always green.

Comment: I experience similar things. Solarized in terminal vim differs from gvim.

Comment: @Chiel92, no that's not the same thing. Unless both are written using the 256 colors palette, you'll **never** get the same colors in GVim and a terminal.

Comment: To the point, I have the same 'green import' issue when in terminal (tCo set to 16, terminator profile is set to solarized and vim is also solarized).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you can check is what `:highlight` groupings are being applied to your import statement, I have a key mapping for a function which can do this:

```
" Show the stack of syntax hilighting classes affecting whatever is under the
" cursor.
function! SynStack()
    echo join(map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")'), " > ")
endfunc

nnoremap <F8> :call SynStack()<CR>
```

If you `:source` a file containing this or put this in your `.vimrc` and reopen vim, we can now check what highlighting is being applied to import.

When I press F8 on an import I receive the message *pythonInclude*, now if you don't see that there may be something wrong with the parsing of python file and the keyword *import* hasn't been picked up on.  We can then look at what rules are being applied to that-

```
:highlight pythonInclude
```

This gives me-

```
pythonInclude  xxx links to Include
```

If we follow this then we can see what rules are being applied to *Include* group. This will probably go deeper, `Include xxx links to PreProc`. If you get this far your highlighting groups are probably correct. If you didn't link to PreProc there maybe another plugin overwriting the highlight group, or a similar issue. You can then check what colors the *PreProc* is setting. You can override a highlight group link, `:highlight link pythonInclude Function` this will now display imports as the same color as Functions!

You can also modify the colors and formatting applied to different highlight groupings however I will leave you to discover those on your own. Much more help can be found in `:h :highlight`, but I hope this helps start your debugging process!

Comment: That is exactly it. In syntax/python.vim I use it has been set to Statement, not Include; changing it to Include makes imports orange; and thus conforming the original theme.